# Transferring a list from function to function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is supposed to take the list from one function to the other. The list will only come with one element. I am a beginner in Python and need some help. The code works, but only brings one element from where the list was created.

When I output the code, I've been using the numbers `high = 100`, `low = 20`, and `multi = 15`. I should have in my list `[90, 75, 60, 45, 30]`. There should be 5 elements coming out of the `show_mulitples` function as a list. I need to take that list into the `show_list` function and count the elements, show the multiples, and get an average. But all that I get is the first element, 90.

```
def main():
    #get the integers
    high = int(input('Enter the high integer for the range '))
    low = int(input('Enter the low integer for the range '))
    multi = int(input('Enter the integer for the multiples '))

    #call the function
    multiples = show_multiples(low, high, multi)

    list_info = show_list(multiples)

#take the arguments into the function
def show_multiples(low, high, multi):
    #make empty list
    multi_list = []

    #make the list
    for i in range(high, low, -1):
        if i % multi == 0:
            multi_list.append(i)
            print('List was created')
            return multi_list

#take the list into the function
def show_list(multiples):

    #create empty total
    total = 0.0

    #add the list together
    for value in multiples:
        total += value

    #get Average
    avg = total / len(multiples)

    print('This list has',len(multiples),'elements')
    print(multiples)    
    print('The average of the multiples is',avg)

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code above, you are returning the list straight after the first element has been added to it. You need to move your return statement out of the loop (NB: In Python indenting is important!).

Try something like:

```
def show_multiples(low, high, multi):   
    #make empty list
    multi_list = []    
    #make the list
    for i in range(high, low, -1):    
        if i % multi == 0:
            multi_list.append(i)
            print('List was created')   
    return multi_list # <-- this should be out of the loop
```

Comment: I tried that and it comes back as a zero in the list.

Comment: @ChukkChukk have you checked whats in your input variables? The function works fine for me.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you very much.  I just started with Python.  I had to go all the way back to the for loop.  Now it works.

Comment: @ChukkChukk no worries, glad it works now! would you mind marking my answer as accepted :)?

Comment: I'm brand new to posting on here, even though I have been looking at the questions on here to help me for the last 2 years.  I just want to make sure I did it correct.  Click on the arrow next to your answer?

Comment: @ChukkChukk the arrows are for up-/downvoting answers, the tick just below is for accepting an answer as the correct solution (just click on it - which you already did - thanks for that).